# Decompose a orthogonal map as orthogonal maps in two directions

Tags: determinant, inner-products, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

Let $R \in O(N)$ be an orthogonal map in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Write $N = N_1 + N_2$. I am wondering if is it possible to find a map $T \in O(N_1)$ and   $L \in O(N_2)$ such that $R(x,y) = (T(x), L(y))$. If it is possible, how to prove it? If this is not true, is it easy to find a counterexample?

Comment: take for example $N = 2$ and $N_1 = N_2 = 1$ and look what happens

Comment: What about if $N \geq 3?$

Comment: well, what happens for $N=2$? what do orthogonal maps look like?